# Is it a way to test exceptions thrown inside of function in JUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, exception, junit

I have this code in Java and I want to test all the code. I have tested all except the part with catch exceptions. I have searched some and couldn't find anything for this, I know I can throw the exceptions from the functions, but I want to have them inside if possible.

```
protected int[][] getJson(String fileName) {
    int[][] array = new int[NUMB_ROW][NUMB_COLUMN];

    try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        // Split string where there aren't a number
        String[] numbers = sb.toString().split("[^-?1-9]");
        int[] intNumbers = new int[NUMB_ROW * NUMB_COLUMN];
        int i = 0;

        // Remove empty spaces and put them in 1d array
        for (String number : numbers) {
            if (!number.equals("")) {
                intNumbers[i++] = Integer.parseInt(number);
            }
        }

        // Convert 1d array to 2d array
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < NUMB_ROW; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < NUMB_COLUMN; col++) {
                array[row][col] = intNumbers[index++];
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        array = null;
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("File not found: %s%n", e.getMessage()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        array = null;
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("IOException: %s%n", e.getMessage()));
    }

     return array;
}
```

Comment: Mock the `logger` and check that it is called with the expected warning message.

Comment: You could also confirm that the returned `array` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks, @dave! That worked and wasn't so much code

Answer (score 4):

You can test if throw exceptions ...
An example how you can do this

```
@Test(expected=IllegalFieldValueException.class)
public void functionOfYourTest() {
    // your code that thrown an exception
    // In this case we will test if will throw an exception
    // of the type IllegalFieldValueException
}
```